# SQL: Insert table -- column name not allowed

Tags: sql, sybase

Ok, maybe a really beginner's question, I have the following table

```
table name: mytable, it has 2 columns: 'ID' and 'Value'.
```

Here's what I want to do. I want to go through 'mytable', find out entries where 'Value=x', and for those entries, I want to add another entry where ID equals the same ID and values=y.

I tried:

```
insert into mytable values (mytable.ID, 'y') where mytable.ID='x'
```

But I got an error: **Only constants, constant expressions, or variables allowed here.  Column names are illegal**

I am using Sybase. what is the correct syntax to do this? thanks.

Comment: You need to use a sub select in the values id... e.g...
insert into mytable values ((select id from mytable where condition='y'), 'y') where mytable.ID='x'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to select from your table and then insert, then you will want to use an `INSERT INTO..SELECT...FROM`:

```
insert into mytable 
select a.ID, 'y'
from mytable a
where a.value='x';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21f81/1).

I am assuming that you meant the where clause to check where the `value='x'` not the `id`.